# scipy.stats.skew nan_policy parameter

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, missing-data

According to scipy docs for skew , we have :

**scipy.stats.skew(a, axis=0, bias=True, nan_policy='propagate')**

where,

> nan_policy : {‘propagate’, ‘raise’, ‘omit’}, optional Defines how to
>   handle when input contains nan. ‘propagate’ returns nan, ‘raise’
>   throws an error, ‘omit’ performs the calculations ignoring nan values.
>   Default is ‘propagate’

So, the default method for `NaN` is propagate. So, how are the NaNs propagated? I can understand the 'omit' method since, it performs calculations by omitting the nan values, and the raise method but, the docs don't seem to help understand how the missing values are treated in case of 'propagate' and how they would be plotted.

Also, would be great, if someone explained the bias parameter too.

**bias : bool, optional
If False, then the calculations are corrected for statistical bias.**

.

Answer (score 0):

It just does computations with the data as is.

```
n [43]: x = np.arange(12, dtype=float).reshape(4, -1)

In [44]: x[2, 1] = np.nan

In [45]: x
Out[45]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,  nan,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.]])

In [46]: stats.skew(x, nan_policy='propagate')
Out[46]: array([  0.,  nan,   0.])
```

Comment: if we do skew([1, 32, 2, 5, np.nan, 134]), the output is nan, so how does it add any meaning? i.e, if np.nan is present in numpy array and nan_policy = 'propagate' then value comes out as always np.nan.

Comment: For 1d arrays, yes. Unless axis is specified, `skew` is documented to operate on the whole array.

Comment: But even for the above 4x3 array, we are getting an array of [0., nan, 0.] right? Also, I was looking at it from a skewed normal distribution point of view, by which I might be passing a 1-D array, right?(This shouldn't even be an issue. Plus, I just tried with axis=None to operate with the whole array x , which also gives np.nan as output. Also, if I were plotting a skewed normal distribution with missing values how would I plot for the np.nans (This is a different question.)

Comment: axis : int or None, optional
Axis along which skewness is calculated. Default is 0. If None, compute over the whole array a. None will compute over the whole array.